# Смещение столбцов и расчет в Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Есть исходный DF:

```
Data    GVKey   MkVal
1   1   5
2   1   6
3   1   7
4   1   8
1   2   7
2   2   5
3   2   8
```

Нам необходимо рассчитать показатель x1 = (MkVal1 - MkVal0)/MkVal0 . То есть текущий год на предыдущий. То есть у нас не будет на выходе значений за 1 год. И нужно учесть что GVkey меняется.
То есть на выходе надо получить:

```
Data    GVKey   MkVal   x1
1   1   5   -
2   1   6   0,2
3   1   7   0,166666667
4   1   8   0,142857143
1   2   7   -
2   2   5   -0,285714286
3   2   8   0,6
```

Проделываем:

`df.groupby('GVKey')['MkVal'].pct_change()`

Получаю:

```
   Data GVKey   MkVal   x1
0   1   1   5   NaN
1   2   1   6   0.200000
2   3   1   7   0.166667
3   4   1   8   0.142857
4   1   2   7   -0.125000
5   2   2   5   -0.285714
6   3   2   8   0.600000
```

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь группировкой и функцией [DataFrameGroupBy.pct_change()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.pct_change.html):

```
In [133]: df['x1'] = df.groupby('GVKey')['MkVal'].pct_change()

In [134]: df
Out[134]:
   Data  GVKey  MkVal        x1
0     1      1      5       NaN
1     2      1      6  0.200000
2     3      1      7  0.166667
3     4      1      8  0.142857
4     1      2      7       NaN
5     2      2      5 -0.285714
6     3      2      8  0.600000
```

PS в решении использовался `Pandas v0.24.2`

---

**UPDATE:** "workaround" для версии `0.23.0`:

```
In [10]: pd.__version__
Out[10]: '0.23.0'

In [11]: df.groupby('GVKey')['MkVal'].transform(lambda x: x.pct_change())
Out[11]:
0         NaN
1    0.200000
2    0.166667
3    0.142857
4         NaN
5   -0.285714
6    0.600000
Name: MkVal, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: Сейчас перепроверил, почему то у меня не появляются `NaN` при переходе между `GVKey`

Comment: Так вот пример в описании дан. Я использую ваш код и у меня только один NaN, хотя должно быть два

Comment: @Max52, «Не верю!» (с) Станиславский. :) Можете привести в вопросе вывод команды “df.groupby('GVKey')['MkVal'].pct_change()” с одним NaN?

Comment: Сейчас приведу.

Comment: Залил на всякий случай: https://dropmefiles.com/AXPi2. Ни в какую не получается(((

Comment: Другие примеры тоже попробовал, все равно только один `NaN`, будто группировка не проводится(((

Comment: В чем же может быть дело?

Comment: @Max52, у меня не получилось воспроизвести ваш результат. Какая у вас версия Pandas?

Comment: А как проверить?

Comment: @Max52, `pd.__version__` или более подробный вариант `pd.show_versions()`

Comment: Обновил до 0.24 , все заработало. Благодарю

Comment: @Max52, а какая у вас была версия до этого?

Comment: 0,23......а теперь перестала часть кода другая работать после обновления(( жесть

Comment: Да я уже обновил, честно не могу сказать)))) было 0.23.x